# Error when adding Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am attempting to update my application for Honeycomb by targeting 
SDK version 11. I'm adding my options as 
items in the action bar with the following in my "/res/menu/ 
fileName.xml":

```
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 
'showAsAction' in package 'android"
```

Comment: By the way, I'm working with Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to properties and check you had set your project build target to build with the Honeycomb SDK.